# F# : filtering None out and keeping only Some

Tags: f#

A quick question on how to effectively group/filter list/seq.

1. Filter for only records where the optional field is not None
2. Remove the "option" parameter to make future processes easier (as None has been filtered out)
3. Group (this is of no problem I believe)

Am I using the best approach?

Thanks!

```
type tmp = {
    A : string
    B : int option }

type tmp2 = {
    A : string
    B : int }



let inline getOrElse (dft: 'a) (x: 'a option) =
    match x with
    | Some v -> v
    | _      -> dft

let getGrouped (l: tmp list) =
    l |> List.filter  (fun a -> a.B.IsSome)
      |> List.map  (fun a -> {A = a.A ; B = (getOrElse 0 (a.B)) })
      |> List.groupBy (fun a -> a.A)
```

Comment: Your getOrElse function is a reinvention of the standard Option.defaultValue function, but as your filter removes list items where B is None you don't need it as B must always be Some int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most natural approach for `map+filter` when `option` is involved is to use `choose`, which combines those two operations and drops the option wrapper from the filtered output.

Your example would look something like this:

```
let getGrouped (l: tmp list) =
    l
    |> List.choose (fun a ->
       a.B 
       |> Option.map (fun b -> {A = a.A; B = b})
    |> List.groupBy (fun a -> a.A)
```

Comment: thanks, I like this approach. At least those functions are clearer in term of signature than those from Deedle.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution is just use the property that an option can be transformed to list with one or zero elements then you can define a function like:

```
let t1 ({A=a; B=b} : tmp) =
        match b with
        | (Some i) -> [{ A = a; B= i}] 
        | _ -> []

let getGrouped (l: tmp list) =
    l |> List.collect t1
      |> List.groupBy (fun a -> a.A)
```